# NSData to HTML NSString using NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I have a question about NSUrlConnection.

I tried to send request to an URL and I would to take the corresponding HTML.

I try with this code:

```
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                           queue:queue
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){

     NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}];
```

I see the correct NSData but the NSString is `nil`. Have I some problem about encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary it returns string, as per [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) it could retrun nil if data encoding is not right.

> Return Value An NSString object initialized by converting the bytes in
>   data into Unicode characters using encoding. The returned object may
>   be different from the original receiver. Returns nil if the
>   initialization fails for some reason (for example if data does not
>   represent valid data for encoding).

make sure your encoding is right.